# How to select MY FACEBOOK WALL instead on MY FACEBOOK PAGES?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post status on my wall. But the code is fetching all my PAGES. I want it to post on my facebook wall, and not on my pages. What should I do? This is my code.

```
$graph_url_pages = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$_SESSION['token'];

$pages = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url_pages)); // get all pages information from above url.
$dropdown = "";
for($i=0;$i<count($pages->data);$i++)
{
    $dropdown .= "<option value='".$pages->data[$i]->access_token."-".$pages->data[$i]->id."'>".$pages->data[$i]->name."</option>";
}
```

Comment: well, if you want to post to your wall, why are you trying to use code that gets your pages? (/me/accounts gets your pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the API call to post to the user wall: `/me/feed`

Detailed information and example code can be found in the docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed#publish

Comment: there is example code in the docs, just open the link. i suggest not using file_get_contents though, use PHP cURL instead. or use the PHP SDK from facebook.